# Parametric typeclass name

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Say we have a heterogeneous list

```
data Nil
data Cons a b
```

I can write code like this for any typeclass `A`

```
class AList a
instance AList Nil
instance (A x, AList xs) => AList (Cons x xs)
```

Now, is there a way to generalize that code so it's parametric in `A`?

Say, like this made up syntax

```
class List (class A) a
instance List (class A) Nil
instance (A x, List (class A) xs) => List (class A) (Cons x xs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand the motivation, but yes, you can express this with GHC’s `ConstraintKinds` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeclasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class List (c :: * -> Constraint) a

data Nil
data Cons a b

instance List c Nil
instance (c x, List c xs) => List c (Cons x xs)
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm just playing around with type-level computation and this is something that I'd like to have.